# Java , add new string object if the length of the chain exceeds a number of character

Tags: java, string, arraylist, newline

I'm trying to add a new String in arraylist if the lenght of this one is too big.

like that;

```
private void createLore(String s) {
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
if(s.lenght > maximumLenght) {
a.add(s /TODO  new object with same string
//it's like a new line .. possible to detect a space ? 
//This avoids the cut of a text
```

Thank's !

Comment: Could you please post an input /output sample?

Comment: Hum , it's with an api , I will explain    : http://i.imgur.com/8voYbER.png as you see , there are 3 lines of text , I want the same thing but with one method because I have to to do that : list.add("Players take ..."); list.add("world. However ..."); ect

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code helps

```
    private void createLore(String s,int maximumLenght) {

       ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(s.trim().length() > maximumLenght) { //s.trim is to trim the additional spaces
             a.add(s); //Add the bigger string to the arraylist
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank's but I made this :

```
 List<String> lores = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = 0;

    String current = "";

    while(i < str.length()){

        current = current + str.charAt(i);

        if((current.length() >= 25 && str.charAt(i) == ' ' && current != "") || i + 1 == str.length()){
            lores.add(current);
            current = "";
        }
        i++;
```